# Is there a way to get the GET Request URL using JavaScript? (not current URL in the browser)

Tags: javascript, http

I want to check if I can read HTTP GET Request URL using JavaScript, but not the current URL.
For example: when I open https://stackoverflow.com/ in my browser and run a chrome network debugger (or any packet sniffer) we see all the requests as shown below.

Here is a sample HTTP Header for reference: I would want to check if I can capture Request URL using JS.

Remote Address:54.243.183.124:80
Request URL:http://l.betrad.com/ct/0_0_0_25650/us/0/1/0/0/0/0/220/250/242/343/0/pixel.gif?v=78f7264&ttid=2&d=view.atdmt.com&r=0.579902658239007
Request Method:GET
Status Code:204 No Content
Request Headersview source

Comment: please provide more details.

Comment: `location.href` returns the URL

Comment: I meant to check http get request not current URL. I modified the question

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "GET request URL". What GET requests? A specific one? All requests ever? Can you clearly and fully explain what you're trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the url using `location.href`. You can get the length of it as simply as

```
var length = location.href.length;
```

Comment: sorry for confusion, I have given more details.